# Balanced Incomplete Block Design (BIBD)

Tags: anova, experiment-design, blocking

If treatment $1$ appears in $r$ blocks and there are $(k-1)$ other treatments in each of those blocks, there are $r(k-1)$ observations in a block containing treatment $1$.

But the following Table does not follow the above statement but the table is said to be BIBD:
$$
   Block
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
1 & 2 &3 &4  \\
\hline
A & A &A & B \\
B & B &C & C \\
C & D &D & D \\
\end{array}
$$
here, $k=3$ , $r=3$

But each block doesn't contain $r(k-1)=3(3-1)=6$ observations rather each block  is containing $3$ observations.

*Where am i doing the mistake?*

Comment: What makes you think that the first sentence is true? It is seemingly directly contradicted by the first line of that sentence. Are you missing a condition?

Comment: @harry In BIBD there are three notation's I think you are confusing them. No. of treatments, No. of Blocks and No. of Treatment in each  block. In your questions seems four treatment, four blocks and three no of treatment in each block.

Comment: @Glen_b I have noted the first sentence from the book `Design and Analysis of Experiments` written by Montogomery , chapter 4, section 4-4.1 Statistical Analysis of BIBD. There is no condition.

Comment: I have had a read of the relevant page. In context, it clearly means to say "there are $r(k-1)$ *other* observations", (i.e. not counting treatment 1).

Comment: @Glen_b But in the context, it has been written that there are $r(k-1)$ observations in `a` block `containing treatment 1`. Or if i don't count  treatment 1 still there is not $6$ observations in `a` block `except treatment 1`. Could you please explain me?

Comment: @ABC please write to the publisher. (Include a link to your question on Cross Validated). _Merci d’avance_

Answer (score 1):

In a balanced incomplete block design (BIBD): all the block have the same size $k$, all pairs of treatments occur together in the same block the same number of times $\lambda$ and there are $\nu$ treatments. The number of replicates of each treatment is $r$.

In your example we have:
$$
  k=3 \\
  \lambda= 2 \qquad \text{example: $A,B$ together in blocks 1,2} \\
  \nu = 4   \qquad A,B,C,D \\
   r=3
$$
Then $n$, the number of experimental runs, is given by $n= \nu \cdot r = 4\cdot 3 = 12$. It can also be calculated as $\binom{\nu}{2}\cdot \lambda = 6 \cdot 2 = 12$.  Now you can use these relations to check what you said.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence:

"If treatment $1$ appears in $r$ blocks and there are $(k−1)$ other treatments in each of those blocks, there are $r(k−1)$ observations in a block containing treatment $1$"

sounds a little bit confusing.

Using Montgomery's notation, the relations $ar=bk$ and $r(k-1)=\lambda(a-1)$ define a BIBD.

That is, given a generic treatment $A$, there are $r$ blocks containing it and $k-1$ other treatments in each of these blocks, so there are $r(k-1)$ pairs.
We can also say that treatment $A$ can be paired with $a-1$ treatments and each of this pairs can appear $\lambda$ times.